# For loop for forecasting several datasets at once in R

Tags: r, for-loop, forecasting

I have a dataset with "Time, Region, Sales" variables and I want to forecast sales for each region using ARIMA or ETS(SES) using `library(forecast)`. There are a total of 70 regions and all of them have 152 observations each and (3 years of data). Something like this:

```
  Week      Region    Sales 
01/1/2011      A       129
07/1/2011      A       140
14/1/2011      A       133
21/1/2011      A       189
...           ...      ...
01/12/2013     Z       324
07/12/2013     Z       210
14/12/2013     Z       155
21/12/2013     Z       386
28/12/2013     Z       266
```

So, I want R to treat every region as a different dataset and perform an `auto.arima`. I am guessing a for loop should be an ideal fit here but I miserably failed with it. 
What I would ideally want it to do is a for loop to run something like this (an auto arima for every 152 observations):

```
fit.A <- auto.arima(data$Sales[1:152])  
fit.B <- auto.arima(data$Sales[153:304])
....
fit.Z <- auto.arima(data$Sales[10490:10640])
```

I came across [this](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/batch-forecasting/) but while converting the dataframe into timeseries, all I got is NAs.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You definitely want to try to avoid `for` loops in `R`. Consider the [`apply` family of functions.](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/) I'm working on an answer but see what you can do with these!

Comment: `apply` is a `for` loop

Comment: True, but good `R` style ought to avoid explicit looping.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Al.Sal! In this case, I am guessing `base::by` is the best to use of all, as it splits dataset by factors. I tried something like `by(data, data$Region, auto.arima(data$Sales))` but I don't think R assumed `auto.arima` as a valid function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the very efficient `data.table` package (assuming your data set called `temp`)

```
library(data.table)
library(forecast)
temp <- setDT(temp)[, list(AR = list(auto.arima(Sales))), by = Region]
```

The last step will save your results in `temp` in a `list` formats (as this is the only format you can store this type of an object).

Afterwords you can do any operation you want on these lists, for example, Inspecting them:

```
temp$AR
#[[1]]
# Series: Sales 
# ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   intercept
# 147.7500
# s.e.    12.0697
# 
# sigma^2 estimated as 582.7:  log likelihood=-18.41
# AIC=40.82   AICc=52.82   BIC=39.59
#
#[[2]]
# Series: Sales 
# ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   intercept
# 268.2000
# s.e.    36.4404
# 
# sigma^2 estimated as 6639:  log likelihood=-29.1
# AIC=62.19   AICc=68.19   BIC=61.41
```

Or plot the forecasts (and etc.)

```
temp[, sapply(AR, function(x) plot(forecast(x, 10)))]
```

Comment: Thanks @David! That was amazing! But I have another question following that..I tried saving the output to a csv file by using `write.csv(temp, file="Arima outputs.csv")` , but this generated an error message instead - `unimplemented type 'list' in EncodeElement.` Is there a way to save it apart from printing it in Console? I need to do be able to use the model for future forecasts.. Thanks again!

Comment: The problem here is that you have lists objects and a csv file doesn't know how to store them. This is unrelated to the solution as a `list` is the only way to store `auto.arima. object. You can either compute specific metrics and save them as data frame or maybe take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330949/r-how-to-save-lists-into-csv)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this easily with `dplyr`. Assuming your data frame is named `df`, run:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)
model_fits <- group_by(df, Region) %>% do(fit=auto.arima(.$Sales))
```

The result is a data frame containing the model fits for each region:

```
> head(model_fits)
Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

  Region        fit
1      A <S3:Arima>
2      B <S3:Arima>
3      C <S3:Arima>
4      D <S3:Arima>
5      E <S3:Arima>
6      F <S3:Arima>
```

You can get a list with each model fit like so:

```
> model_fits$fit
[[1]]
Series: .$Sales 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
      intercept
       196.0000
s.e.    14.4486

sigma^2 estimated as 2088:  log likelihood=-52.41
AIC=108.82   AICc=110.53   BIC=109.42

[[2]]
Series: .$Sales 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
      intercept
       179.2000
s.e.    14.3561

sigma^2 estimated as 2061:  log likelihood=-52.34
AIC=108.69   AICc=110.4   BIC=109.29
```

Comment: That really helped..thanks! Now, to this if I want to add `freq=7` for weekly seasonality, how do I do that? I cannot read the data in timeseries format to mention freq while reading it itself, since `ts` function allows to read only single variable data which would mean I can read only the `sales` column and not the `region` column. I tried something like `model_fits <- group_by(df, Region) %>% do(fit=auto.arima(.$Sales),freq=7)` but I don't think it's the right way.

Comment: I also tried reading the `sales` as a `timeseries` dataset and calling `region` from its orginal dataframe, something like:
`model_fits <- group_by(ts.sales, df$Region) %>% do(fit=auto.arima(.$Sales))`
 but the error I get is this: 
`Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "ts"`

Comment: You can specify your own functions to `dplyr` rather than calling `auto.arima` directly. Example: `model_fits <- group_by(df, Region) %>% do(fit=shraddha_wins(.$Sales, freq=7))` Within such a function, you can then apply the logic that you describe above. I'd recommend that you write a function and test it with the `Sales` from the first `Region`. Once the function behaves as desired, then apply the `group_by` operation.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion..i will try doing that.. by the way +1 for "shraddha_wins" :D