# List with different row lengths to CSV in R

Tags: r

I am having a list that looks like this:

```
City | Country | TrainArrivals  
A | country_1 | 8.00, 9.30, 10.00, 15.15  
B | country_1 | 11.00, 12.30, 18.00, 22.20, 22.50  
C | country_2 | 8.10, 11.20, 13.00, 16.40, 19.20, 23.00
```

So it is all saved as a list (called `data`). Here I have to point out that `data$TrainArrivals` is also of type `list` and from different lengths.

I have tried looking for some solutions [like this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330949/r-how-to-save-lists-into-csv) Or calling this line:

```
capture.output(summary(data), file = paste(path, "values.csv", sep = "/"))
```

but the `.csv` file didn't have the data, but instead infromation of which type, length is every column.

I tried calling this line:  `do.call("rbind", lapply(data, as.data.frame))` and I got the following error

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
> check.names = TRUE,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows:

So, does anyone have an idea how could I solve the problem?

**EDIT** So the output from **dput(data)**

```
    structure(list(scenario = "first", pr = "all", rep = "2", 
    plot_data = list(c(81677L, 91437L, 233376L, 71580L, 43126L, 
    28724L, 15453L, 11162L, 8355L, 6786L, 5756L, 5162L, 4473L, 
    3848L, 3617L, 3331L, 2941L, 2572L, 2289L, 1974L, 1797L, 1575L, 
    1325L, 1217L, 1012L, 886L, 787L, 709L, 548L, 409L, 399L, 
    339L, 292L, 215L, 128L, 113L, 83L, 61L, 42L, 30L, 18L, 15L, 
    6L, 12L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L))), .Names = c("first", 
"pr", "rep", "plot_data"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), groups = structure(list(
    scenario = "first", pr = "all", .rows = structure(list(
        1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "list"))), .Names = c("scenario", "pr", ".rows"), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Desired output**

```
City; Country; trainArrivals;  
A;country_1;8.00, 9.30, 10.00, 15.15;
B;country_1;11.00, 12.30, 18.00, 22.20, 22.50;  
C;country_2;8.10, 11.20, 13.00, 16.40, 19.20, 23.00;
```

Comment: Is that a `list`, or a `data.frame` with a list-column? It may help immensely if you provided the output from `dput(data)` here.

Comment: @r2evans I have the problem that I have made a simple example of my real problem. when I try to post the dput of the orgiinal problem I get "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 36646."

Comment: `dput(head(data,3))` or `dput(data[1:3,1:4])`? We don't need all data, we really need *just enough* to get the point across. :-)

Comment: okay I did dput(data[3,]), I think that should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** for the newer data.

You've formatted it in the question like a `data.frame` with a list-column, so I'll go off of that.

A couple options:

1. Store as json, so that any language immediately gets the correct structure:

   ```r
   writeLines(jsonlite::toJSON(dat), "dat.json")
   str( jsonlite::read_json("dat.json", simplifyDataFrame = TRUE) )
   # 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  4 variables:
   #  $ first    : chr "first"
   #  $ pr       : chr "all"
   #  $ rep      : chr "2"
   #  $ plot_data:List of 1
   #   ..$ : int  81677 91437 233376 71580 43126 28724 15453 11162 8355 6786 ...
   ```
2. Collapse the list-column into something easily undone. I'll use `collapse=","` here, though you can use any character known to not be in the data. (I find `","` to be intuitive for other users.)

   Note that this modifies your data in-place, so if you do this, you'll either want to do it on a temporary copy of it, or you'll need to manually undo it on your real data.

   To distinguish the nested list separator from the normal tabular field separator, I'll use `write.table(., sep="|")`, as much for visual *here* as anything. Note that as long as you have normal quoting, you can use `","` for *both* and it will parse correctly ... though it'll be a little more difficult for the eye to see the distinction.

   ```r
   dat$plot_data <- sapply(dat$plot_data, paste, collapse = ",")
   write.table(dat, "dat.txt", sep = ";", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
   invisible(sapply(readLines("dat.txt"), cat, "\n"))
   # first;pr;rep;plot_data 
   # first;all;2;81677,91437,233376,71580,43126,28724,15453,11162,8355,6786,5756,5162,4473,3848,3617,3331,2941,2572,2289,1974,1797,1575,1325,1217,1012,886,787,709,548,409,399,339,292,215,128,113,83,61,42,30,18,15,6,12,4,1,0,1,1,0,1 

   newdat <- read.table("dat.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
   newdat$plot_data <- lapply(strsplit(newdat$plot_data, "[,[:space:]]+"), as.integer)
   str(newdat)
   # 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  4 variables:
   #  $ first    : chr "first"
   #  $ pr       : chr "all"
   #  $ rep      : int 2
   #  $ plot_data:List of 1
   #   ..$ : int  81677 91437 233376 71580 43126 28724 15453 11162 8355 6786 ...
   ```

Comment: I have updated my question with desired output. I am not sure if what you are suggesting is giving the same

Comment: Replace my `write.table(., sep="|")` with `write.table(., sep=";", quote=FALSE)`.